# search news by keyword using Google CSE

Tags: search, rss, keyword, google-custom-search, google-news

I want to search results from "Google News" via "Google Custom Search Engine Api (CSE)" based on location/country and keyword.

I tried using it by setting up a CSE which only searches inside the site "news.google.com" but then it only returns *old news article clippings*. Not sure how to grab the recent news articles. Also, i noticed that if we set schema type NewsArticle, its not accurate as not all news sites having this schema type of page.

I knew that there is a workaround to use RSS feeds for getting google news and it returns results as required. Example - https://news.google.com/news/feeds?hl=en&q=corruption&ie=utf-8&num=10&output=rss . But, I afraid this is not a correct and recommended way to get go with.

Will appreciate if anyone could advice right setting in CSE or other recommended solution.