# Retrieve google news through Google CSE Api

Tags: rest, google-custom-search, scalable, google-news

I am searching a solution to retrieve news from google news.

I am already retrieving the news from the RSS feed. But this is not scalable, and I will get blacklisted.

I wanted to use Google CSE API (with billing option, I want to be able to send more than 100 000 queries per month), but it seems not to be possible to use it directly with google news. (it seems to be only working with google image, or global web search)

I have already read about Bing Search API, and Yahoo Boss API. I want to know if there is a way with google news. I have already tried to set the site only to google news, but I am getting old news article clippings.

I have already read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824389/search-news-by-keyword-using-google-cse)(but there is no answer) and [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806200/what-to-use-now-google-news-api-is-deprecated) had no new solution for me.

Is there a billable way of doing high volume query directly to google news ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We (Google) currently don't offer programatic access to Google News, and unfortunately I'm not aware of any plans to change that. 
You can still use RSS though for free, just watch out for the number of requests you send our way.

Comment: Any ballpark figure of what number of requests is appropriate?